# np.select Int64 and int64 difference

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, types

```
def apply_km_cluster(df):
    conditions = [
        (df['value'].between(0, 20000)),            # Between 0 and 20,000
        (df['value'].between(20000, 50000)),        # Between 20,000 and 50,000
        (df['value'].between(50000, 100000)),       # Between 50,000 and 100,000
        (df['value'].between(100000, 200000)),      # Between 100,000 and 200,000
        (df['value'] >= 200000)                     # Greater than or equal to 200,000
    ]

    values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]   # Assign values for each condition.
    df['cluster'] = np.select(conditions, values)  
    return df
```

Hi, i have df and value column be Int64 type and if i use np.select like this i get "TypeError: invalid entry 0 in condlist: should be boolean ndarray". After some research, i convert int64 type and error be resolved why Int64 get this error i cant understand, any explian.

I tried Int64 and int64 types in np.select and expect it to work for both.

Comment: Numpy does not recognise pandas objects, specifically the BooleanArray

Comment: `np.select` is a numpy function.  `Int64` is a pandas extension  dtype. Have you looked at the individual condition terms? `(df['value'].between(0, 20000))`  What's it's dtype?  Any difference between the `Int` and `int` cases?

Comment: If you aren't satisfied with the answer, you'll need to give a sample `df['Value']` series, so we can test and demonstrate what's happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`np.select` has a test

```
# If cond array is not an ndarray in boolean format or scalar bool, abort.
for i, cond in enumerate(condlist):
    if cond.dtype.type is not np.bool_:
        raise TypeError(
            'invalid entry {} in condlist: should be boolean ndarray'.format(i))
```

If `df` is a dataframe with `Int64` dtype:

```
In [316]: df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 6 entries, 0 to 5
Data columns (total 1 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype
---  ------  --------------  -----
 0   value   6 non-null      Int64
dtypes: Int64(1)
memory usage: 182.0 bytes

In [317]: df['value'].between(0, 20000).values
Out[317]: 
<BooleanArray>
[False, False, False, True, True, False]
Length: 6, dtype: boolean

In [318]: _.dtype
Out[318]: BooleanDtype
```

The `values` is `BooleanArray` with a pandas extension dtype.  At least for now, `np.select` cannot handle conditions that yield extended dtypes.  I believe the pandas extended dtype are still considered experimental.

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/boolean.html

```
BooleanArray is currently experimental. Its API or implementation may change without warning.
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it was clear for me.

Answer (score 2):

You might consider [`cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html)*ting* your data and make the `labels` for the clusters :

```
def apply_km_cluster(df):
    bins = [0, 20000, 50000, 100000, 200000, np.inf]
    labels = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

    df["cluster"] = pd.cut(
        df["value"], bins=bins, labels=labels, include_lowest=True
    )

    return df
```

But you to answer your question, the `TypeError` is due to an open issue (*see [GH43228](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/43228)*).

What I see as a workaround is this :

```
conditions = [s.fillna(False).astype(bool) for s in conditions]

df['cluster'] = np.select(conditions, values, default=pd.NA) # adjust the dft
```

Output :

```
print(df.pipe(apply_km_cluster))

    value cluster
0  250000       5
1   60000       3
2   30000       2
3    <NA>    <NA>
4   15000       1
5  125000       4
```

Used input :

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"value": [250000, 60000, 30000, np.nan, 15000, 125000]}, dtype="Int64"
)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but what I was really wondering was why the Int64 type does not work for np.select in a column where all values are non-nan, but why it works for int64.